# RDS does not issue CALs on Windows Server 2012 Essentials

Tags: rds, essentials-2012, windows-server-essentials

I'm trying to get RDS services running on a clean install of Windows Server 2012.

I followed this example http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2833839?wa=wsignin1.0

The licensing server is activated, and CALs installed OK.  Nothing is reporting errors.

But when a users tries to log in, the system does not issue a CAL.

Only the 2 administrative sessions are allowed.

The machine is a AD DC, but doesn't need to be.  This server was intended to run in an isolated environment (of 1 server only) for users to log on and run our suite of applications.

What am I doing wrong, or what options do I have?  I know hardly anything about Windows Servers.

Comment: I did not install the RD Connection Broker Role, the previous link I posted details on how to set up without it.

Comment: Aha, I see. I actually tried to do something very similar to this last week. When Server Manager complained about the [Connection Broker role not being allowed on a Domain Controller](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2799605), I decided to run the DC in a VM instead. That worked perfectly, and gave me full functionality.

Comment: With Essentials, you don't have virtualization rights though to do that.

Comment: Good point. Though the price difference is so small that I think I'd just use Standard and not even consider Essentials for anything.

Comment: Yes, hindsight is 20/20.  I would do that now, but it's already been purchased.  Offtopic question, can I upgrade it?

Comment: According to replies [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winserverTS/thread/bbf47aa2-8ae5-4f22-9827-afee5a11417a/), RDS installation on a WS2012 DC not only fails to work, but even fails to uninstall cleanly, and may require a restore from backup…

Comment: As for upgrading — technically you can [transition an existing installation to Windows Server 2012 Standard](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj247582.aspx), which removes the 25 user limitation, but not the RDS incompatibility with DC on the same server instance.

Comment: @SergeyVlasov thanks!  That is probably what i'll have to do, but i'd rather not have to purchase anything else.  But then i'll have virtualization rights.  Run one instance as DC, another as my RDS.  I'll ponder over it this weekend unless another solution arrises.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not install RDSH or Hyper-V on Windows server 2012 Essentials.

It's also dangerous to allow non-administrative users to remotely access an domain controller.